# Slack bot getting information from threads and messages?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack bots can get information about messages that have just been posted with the "messages" event. So why can't they get information about all the messages in a thread?

So for example when someone makes a reply to a message in a thread a message event is fired with the subtype of "message_replied" however the text fields of all of the messages in the result are out of scope for the bot.

Is there a way to access this information? I have tried using things like channels.replies and conversations.replies but the results of those are out of scope for the bot too. Requiring the channels:history scope.

I would settle for the bot being able to read the content of its own messages only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access threads with your bot via API method `conversations.replies` (or the pendant methods) by using the user token from your Slack app. A Slack app with bot users always has both a user token (with rights inherited from the original installer) and a bot token.

As the documentation says in section [Threading messages](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading#finding_message_threads_in_the_wild):

> While Slack app-based bot users can't access these methods directly,
>   user tokens granted with the correlating scope can.